# Rhythmbox doesn't sound anymore

Tags: rhythmbox

Quite recently, Rhythmbox has stopped sounding. I can't find any internal volume control in Rhythmbox and the other applications sound fine. I have Ubuntu 18.04. What could be the problem?

Comment: What media files does this happen to?

Comment: I only tried .mp3

Comment: In your Settings, under Sound -> Applications, is it muted or disabled there?

Comment: @Robby1212 That was it! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments on the question in this particular instance the issue was that Rhythmbox was muted in settings.

Navigating to Seetings -> Sound -> Applications and then making sure Rhythmbox was turned on fixed the issue.